# NLP: how to find name and numbers from given text using python NLTK

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I have different text, I need to capture names and numbers.

Here is some example text which I need to process:

> 1.Claims 1-3, 9-12, and 18 are rejected under 35 U.S.C. 103(a) as being unpatentable over Olarig et al. (U.S. Patent No. 5,944,809)
>   (“Olarig”) and Solomita (U.S. Patent No. 7,581,052).
>
> 2.Claims 16 is rejected under 35 U.S.C. 103(a) as being unpatentable over US-2005/0013154 Honda et al., and further in view of
>   US-2003/0189860 Takeuchi et al., and further in view of US6883060
>   Hayama, and further in view of US-2004/0088473 Ogle.

I need to capture names and number in the same order they appear in the text.

For 1, list should be:

```
list1 = [{'name':'Olarig et al','patent no':'5944809'},
         {'name':'Solomita','patent no':'7581052'}]
```

For 2, captured list should be:

```
list2 = [{'name':'Honda et al', 'patent no':'20050013154'},
         {'name':'Takeuchi et al', 'patent no':'6883060'},
         {'name':'Ogla' , 'patent no':'20040088473'}]
```

What are the steps needed to achieve lists from text?

Comment: And.. what have you tried?

Comment: This is harder to machine than it looks to human being. Heavy research is conducted on legal and patent documents. There is even a separate topic, which is **entity recognition**.

Comment: Doing it manually will be faster than trying to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an entity recognition problem.
I would probably start by making separate parsers for each entity you want to recognize and working up from there.

For ex: make the 'Patent' identifier, which from your example looks like you will have to recognize -- ignoring case --  'Patent No. xxxxxxx'   or 'USxxxxxxx'   and probably more formats.  You will need to create regex's for these, or train a classifier to recognize them (harder but possibly more accurate).  I personally recommend starting with a regex parser for each entity, and then just keep testing until you're satisfied!